# How to make an image disabled when the sound plays and get back to enabled when the sound finishes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look at this simple code

```
<head>

<style>
audio { display:none;}
img {
 width: 25px;
 content:url(mybutton.png);
}
img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>
function playSound (mysound) {
    let theSound = new Audio(mysound);
    theSound.play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img onclick="playSound('ch.m4a')" />
</body>
```

**I want a very simple css or javascript code** that would do these:

-When the image got clicked, it got disabled (ie even the user clicks on it, it will not call the function). Then, the sound started to play.

-When the sound stopped playing, the image changed back to be enabled.

**Could we do that using very simple code?**

Comment: The blurring part should be easy enough to research. Combine with a handler for the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event of your audio element, to remove the blurring again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an event listener to your `Audio` and apply your css changes there using a css class:

javascript

```js
function playSound (mysound, img) {

    if (img)
      img.classList.add("blurry");

    let theSound = new Audio(mysound);
    theSound.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      if (img)
        img.classList.remove("blurry");
    });
    theSound.play();
  }
```

css

```css
.blurry { filter: blur(4px); }
```

html

```html
<img onclick="playSound('ch.m4a', this)" />
```

Comment: Can you make the image **disabled** when the sound is playing and get back to **enabled** when the sound stops?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? prevent multiple sounds? you can't "disable" an image.

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent multiple sounds. Can I make the image hidden and reappear?

Comment: I found   img.style.visibility = "hidden"; "visible"

Comment: you could also add a `display: none;` to the `.blurry` class.